# Managing Log files with distillery

Tags: logging, elixir, distillery

### Background

Using distillery to start an OTP App, I noticed that all the logs go to the `./var/log/` folder to 2 different files:

- erlang.log.1
- run_erl.log

### Problems

I have issues here:

1. I don’t know what `run_erl.log` is supposed to log
2. I would like to change the default log path from `./var/log/erlang.log.1` to `./log/myapp.log`

### Research

I have checked this discussion for some hints, but according to it I have to change the configurations on the `:logger` extra app.

[Log files in Distillery releases](https://elixirforum.com/t/log-files-in-distillery-releases/10701)

This search led me to the following code snippet which uses `:logger_file_backend`

https://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/773-logging-to-a-file-with-elixir

However I think I am chasing a wild goose here. I don’t think that the solution to my problem lies in adding more dependencies, but rather in changing some configuration for the `:logger` app.

I just don’t know where nor how.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using `bin/your_app start` to start your application? In that case perhaps `RUNNER_LOG_DIR` is a variable you're looking for to customize the log output directory.

I did a small research and noticed the issue "[how to configure the path of the run_erl (for erlang.log.X, run_erl.log files)](https://github.com/erlware/relx/issues/595)" that is similar to yours. `RUNNER_LOG_DIR` is mentioned during the discussion.

`distillery`, in turn, lists [`RUNNER_LOG_DIR`](https://github.com/bitwalker/distillery/blame/da3a69c7de8e78bc92284f8323c9eea5926a1205/docs/extensibility/shell_scripts.md#L87) as a configurable environment variable. It is then used when starting your application [here](https://github.com/bitwalker/distillery/blob/b4a9ab4b86984a437b7e555596ccd91f68e83a36/priv/libexec/commands/start.sh#L48).

---

> I don’t know what `run_erl.log` is supposed to log.

Per official Erlang [documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/man/run_erl.html), `run_erl.log` is used to log progress and warnings from the `run_erl` program itself. `run_erl` is a program that starts the application.

> I would like to change the default log path from `./var/log/erlang.log.1` to `./log/myapp.log`.

Per my findings it should be possible to change the location of the log files, but I'm yet to see if it is possible to change the name of the file too (`erlang.log.1 -> myapp.log`), if that's also what you are asking. If you really need to change the name of the file, I'd look into symlinking `myapp.log` and `erlang.log.1`.